# How to find a specific spanning subgraph?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, iteration, subset

A **spanning subgraph** is a subgraph that contains all the vertices of the original graph.

Given a graph $G$, I would like to write a function $f$ for finding a ***spanning 5-regular bipartite connected*** subgraph of $G$. More specifically, if $G$ does not contain such graphs, $f$ gives `False`, otherwise $f$ gives `True` and a subgraph that satisfies the conditions above.

I wrote a piece of code for this. This code seems to work well when the number of edges of $G$ is small.

```
(* test if a given graph is k-regular*)
kRegularQ[g_, k_] := 
  Max[VertexDegree[g]] == k && Min[VertexDegree[g]] == k;

(*main function*)
FindspanningBiGraph[graph_] := Module[
  {g = graph, Csubsets, gtest, i},
  Csubsets = Subsets[EdgeList@g, {5*VertexCount[g]/2}];
  Do[gtest = Graph[Csubsets[[i]]]; 
   If[kRegularQ[gtest, 5] &&  ConnectedGraphQ[gtest] && 
     BipartiteGraphQ[gtest], Print[{"True", gtest}] && Break[]], {i, 
    Length[Csubsets]}]
  ]
```

```
g = CompleteGraph[{6, 6}]
FindspanningBiGraph[g]
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

First of all, this function is written with some defects that **occupy too much memory** and **run slowly**. The `Subsets` function, in particular, is seems not good when the number of edges of a graph is dense.

[image]

Wish there is a better way to handle it. Maybe the iteration will work. However, I have not mastered Mathematica's subset iteration method well. Or there is **a better algorithm** for this particular problem. After all, these subgraphs are special. The tactics we choose in  the search are violent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As OP points out, one limitation is

```
Subsets[EdgeList@g,{5*VertexCount[g]/2}]
```

For example, if `g` is `CompleteGraph[n]` then there are `Binomial[Binomial[n,2],5*n/2]` many such subsets when $n$ is even, which for $n=10$ is equal to $3169870830126$.

OPs problem involves several conditions, but to get started, let us take the problem of listing all subgraphs where the [vertex degrees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_(graph_theory)) are prescribed, in a more efficient way. For example

```
subgraphs[CompleteGraph[5],{3,3,2,2,2}]
```

should return all subgraphs where vertices 1,2,3,4,5 have degrees 3,3,2,2,2 respectively. To remove isomorphic ones, one would use

```
subgraphs[CompleteGraph[5],{3,3,2,2,2}]//DeleteDuplicates[#,IsomorphicGraphQ]&
```

Using the code below, the result is

[image]

**What algorithm?** I use the following. Step 1: Choose a subset of the edges starting from vertex 1 (as many as needed). Step 2: Choose a subset of the edges starting from vertex 2 to vertices $>2$ (as many as needed taking into account that we may already have selected an edge from vertex $1$ to vertex $2$). Step 3: Choose a subset of the edges starting from vertex 3 to vertices $>3$ (as many as needed taking into account that we may already have selected edges from vertices $<3$ to vertex $3$). And so on.

In this approach, the choice made at Step 1 influences the choices available in later steps, and so on. Probably there is a clever way to implement this kind of "dependent choice" problem exploiting functionality available in Mathematica, but I came up with the following using recursion:

```
to[g_]:=Lookup[GroupBy[List@@@EdgeList[g],Min,Max@@@#&],
          Sort[VertexList[g]],{}]-Sort[VertexList[g]];
from[sg_]:=Graph[Join@@MapIndexed[Function[{x,p},
              Map[UndirectedEdge[First[p],#]&,First[p]+x]],sg]];
subgraphs[{},{},{}]:={{}};
subgraphs[el_List,d:{__Integer},max:{__}]:=If[Length[el]===Length[d],
  If[MatchQ[d,{___,_?Negative,___}],{},
    Join@@Map[Function[{s},Map[Join[{s},#]&,subgraphs[Rest[el],
      MapAt[#-1&,Rest[d],Transpose[{s}]],Rest[max]]]],
        Subsets[First[el],{First[d]}]//If[Length[#]>First[max],
          #[[1;;First[max]]],#]&]],Abort[]];
subgraphs[g_Graph,d:{__Integer},max_:{}]:=Map[from,subgraphs[to[g],d,
     If[max==={},ConstantArray[Infinity,Length[d]],max]]];
```

**Examples (now including `BipartiteGraphQ`).**

- The example mentioned by OP is obtained using

```
Select[subgraphs[CompleteGraph[{6,6}],ConstantArray[5,12]]
  //DeleteDuplicates[#,IsomorphicGraphQ]&,BipartiteGraphQ]
```

and takes about 1 second, which is much faster than OPs code

[image]

Unlike OPs program, this program makes a complete list, therefore we can also conclude that this is the only subgraph that satisfies the criteria, up to isomorphism.

- It also works for `CompleteGraph[10]` using

```
Select[subgraphs[CompleteGraph[10],ConstantArray[5,10],
         Join[{1},ConstantArray[Infinity,9]]],BipartiteGraphQ]
```

This takes about 250 seconds. The result is

[image]

The result itself is not very interesting, it is simply `CompleteGraph[{5,5}]`, but the point is that the computation finished in 250 seconds. But note that in this last example, I called `subgraphs` with three arguments, the third argument being `{1,Infinity,...,Infinity}`. The point of this is to restrict the search space a little bit. The `1` in this case says that in Step 1 only one choice is made. This is no big deal in the case of `CompleteGraph[10]` since all those choices are isomorphic.

**Note.** The code assumed that the vertex labels are numbers.